# Inserting multiple arrays into MongoDB using NodeJS Post route

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, curl, mongoose

I am building a simple recipe insertion tool in NodeJS and MongoDB in order to understand the MEAN stack. Each recipe has a title, description and ingredient arrays (there can be multiple ingredient arrays), which have the ingredient name. I tried running a simple cURL query to insert a test recipe into the DB and was presented with the following error: `Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined`, at the following line: `name: req.ingredients.name`. There are 2 questions in this post. The first one is (and it might answer the second one too), is the following approach correct when inserting data into the DB? Secondly, what's wrong with the array insertion that's throwing this error? Since there could be multiple "ingredient" arrays, will the approach below throw an error during execution?

**routes\index.js**

```
router.post('/recipes', function(req, res, next) {
  var recipe = new Recipe();
  recipe.description = req.description;
  recipe.title = req.title;
  recipe.ingredients = [{
    name: req.ingredients.name
  }];

  recipe.save(function(err, recipe){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(recipe);
  });
});
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more details.

**EDIT: Added additional details**

```
C:\>curl --data "description=howdy&title=test&ingredient[name]=apple" http://localhost:3000/recipes
<h1>Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined</h1>
<h2></h2>
<pre>TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;name&#39; of undefined
    at C:\app\routes\index.js:33:26
    ...
```

Comment: The required detail here would be to include the data you are POSTing via cURL, and in fact the command to even see if the cURL syntax is correct. Then of course depending on what that looks like, also show how `req.ingredients` looks like when you "log" the variable as you might have parser issues with the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a "typo" in there where that should be called "ingredients" and not "ingredient" as you have there. But also your notation is not "strictly" an array as you should mean to do:

The defauly format of cURL is x-www-formencoded, so that is what it expects the data to be. So if I do a quick test using jQuery [`.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) I get:

```
$.param({ "ingredients": [ { "name": "apple" }, { "name": "orange" }] })
```

Which comes out as:

```
"ingredients%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=apple&ingredients%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=orange"
```

Or translating from the already encoded form ( help from [here](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) ) then you get:

```
"ingredients[0][name]=apple&ingredients[1][name]=orange"
```

Which represents the same thing as the data structure I used as input.

Do that an then `req.ingredients` should be an "array" already as long as you have the correct parser in place to decode the encoded URL. See [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) for correct setup.

Then you just do:

```
req.ingredients.forEach(function(ingredient) {
    recipe.ingredients.push(ingredient);
})
```

In order to add each array element within the array to the array property in your created document.